# Does same refractive index for two objects mean that no reflection of light will take place? if yes then why?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, refraction

I have had this doubt since I read the vanishing glass bowl in glycerin. If you know about that then please explain the phenomena behind it.

Comment: If the refractive index is the same, how does the photon realize anything is different?

Comment: You do not give any explanation of your doubts and you do not show any efforts from your side two find an answer. Also, there are countless video demonstrations on the internet which also give an expert explanation of the phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

Light interacts with a dielectric because the oscillating electric field associated with the light polarises the electron density within the dielectric, and this produces oscillating electric dipoles. These oscillating dipoles then reradiate light that interferes with the incident light and change its speed of propagation. It is the change in the strength of this interaction that causes the light to reflect at an interface.

The refractive index is related to the strength of the interaction between the light and the dielectric, so if the refractive index is the same either side of an interface that means the interaction of the light with the two materials is the same. And if the light interacts in the same way with both materials it is unaffected by passing though a boundary between them.

It might seem strange that a solid like glass and a liquid like glycerine can interact with light in the same way, but remember that the wavelength of light is much greater than the sizes of the molecules in the glass or glycerin. As far as the light is concerned both glass and glycerine are just a mass of electrons. If the interaction of the light with the electrons is the same in both glass and glycerine the light will propagate at the same speed in both of them.